# Regulating the sum in Casimir Force

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, casimir-effect

I am trying to evaluate the [Casimir force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) using a Gaussian regulator (I know there are other much easier ways to do this, but I want to try this!) We then are reduced to evaluating the sum

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-\alpha n^2} $$

Moreover, I am interested in the series expansion of the above sum around $\alpha = 0$. Any ideas how I would go about obtaining this sum?

PS - I don't want to use the Euler-Mclaurin formula.That was used to show that a general regulator would always give one the same answer, so this would just be a special case of the that proof and not a very novel way. Any other ideas?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40822/2451 http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39811/11127 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26877/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I only know of solving this using the Euler-Maclaurin series. However Prahar is correct that from there it closely follows the general regulator proof

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can just use the Taylor expansion of the exponential 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-\alpha n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \sum_m \frac{(-\alpha n^2)^m}{m!}$$
and use the definition of the Riemann zeta function $$\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$ 
so you have $$\sum_m \frac{(-\alpha)^{m})\zeta(-2m-1)}{m!}$$
and finally use the zeta function regularization.

Comment: Hi JAAT, welcome to physics.SE! This looks promising, but I'm not sure it's going to work. Can you elaborate? Thanks!